# Merge list of dictionaries by key, check for values - add if new, update if different

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I'm trying to get rid of duplicated dictionaries with the same keys (by merging them), but also need to keep track of the values they contain. I have 2 lists:

```
person_list_1 = [
    {"name": "John",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Audi", "model_year": 2001},
                {"make": "BMW", "model_year": 2009}
            ]
    },
    {"name": "Mary",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Mazda", "model_year": 2003}
            ]
    },
]

person_list_2 = [
    {"name": "John",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Audi", "model_year": 2017},
                {"make": "Volkswagen", "model_year": 2008}
            ]
    },
    {"name": "Ben",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Ford", "model_year": 1984}
            ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, two of them have the same `name` key, but the values are kind of different.

I would like it to look like this eventually:

```
updated_person_list = [
    {"name": "John",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Audi", "model_year": 2017},
                {"make": "BMW", "model_year": 2009},
                {"make": "Volkswagen", "model_year": 2008},
            ]
    },
    {"name": "Mary",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Mazda", "model_year": 2003},
            ]
    },
    {"name": "Ben",
     "cars": [
                {"make": "Ford", "model_year": 1984}
            ]
    },
]
```

I.e., find matching dictionary keys between both lists and account for them accordingly -
if such a car already exists in the "cars" list but with a different production year, update the nested dictionary.

Tried out many different solutions including `collections.defaultdict`, `itertools.chain`, etc, but none of those attempts was successful.
Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Maybe you've got something that'd be better modeled using SQL and some ORM? What happens when you need to remove "cars" from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over dictionaries and accumulate the items inside temporary dictionary with names as a keys and values as dictionary of cars from make to dict of cars, and finally we convert this dictionary to our desired dictionary:

```python
def iterate(acc, l):
    for p in l:
        name = p["name"]
        if not name in acc:
            acc[name] = {}
        for c in p["cars"]:
            acc[name][c["make"]] = c

def merge(l1, l2):
    acc = {}
    iterate(acc, l1)
    iterate(acc, l2)
    return acc

def convert(acc):
    resp = []
    for k, v in acc.items():
        resp.append({"name": k, "cars": list(v.values())})
    return resp
```

We can use this functions as:

```python
print(convert(merge(person_list_1, person_list_2)))
```

The result will be:

```python
[
    {'name': 'John', 'cars': [
        {'make': 'Audi', 'model_year': 2017},
        {'make': 'BMW', 'model_year': 2009},
        {'make': 'Volkswagen', 'model_year': 2008}]
     },
    {'name': 'Mary', 'cars': [
        {'make': 'Mazda', 'model_year': 2003}
    ]
    },
    {'name': 'Ben', 'cars': [
        {'make': 'Ford', 'model_year': 1984}
    ]
    }
]
```